# How to Level Collar Ties to Install Drywall

Tags: drywall, framing, ceiling, attic

I am doing a hybrid renovation of the attic/second floor of our 1924 cape cod style home . We hired out for the code-related trades (framing, electrical, insulation) and are DIY-ing the rest (drywall, refinishing floors, etc). We're about ready to hang drywall and have discovered that our framer didn't install the collar ties level all the way across the room. What is the best/easiest way to level the collar ties without losing undue head height (our max head height is only like 7'-8" so every inch is precious). [image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the "right" way, but what I'd do is basically sister 2x4s to the collar ties and lower the ceiling whatever amount is needed to get "close enough" to flat.  Note, it doesn't need to be *perfectly* flat.

Comment: Using 2 string lines drawn really tight to minimize sag on either side aids in getting the sistering 2X on the same plane. Keep the string line off the bottom of the 2X using a scrap of wood, and use the same thickness of scrap to use as a gauge to set the 2X sisters. Setting the string line tight to the new pieces will allow each new member to push down the string as you go creating a gradual drop in the ceiling, then as you get to the other side, it will rapidly go back up. Another tip, it looks like a really long run, resupport the string line in the middle.